# GTM valuable defining - after if condition its not giving proper result

Tags: arrays, google-tag-manager

I am absolute beginner to GTM Javascript, I would appreciate some help.

I need to exctract info from raw data in dataLayer to use it as variable for GTM code. I need to sum  fees of the prices of the products, and I have a list of brands (BRANDC, BRANDD), where the fee is in other amount than in the rest of the brands (these brands are indefinitive). I tried to do the following, but it is not working, and don´t know why.

I have a dataLayer:

```
({"products":[{"name":"Product1","id":"xyz","price":"103.31","quantity":1,"brand":"BRANDA"},{"name":"Product2","id":"xzy","price":"99.00","quantity":1,"brand":"BRANDB"},{"name":"Product3","id":"zyx","price":"30.00","quantity":1,"brand":"BRANDC"}]});
```

I managed to extract the data to variable productList, then I have tried to create two variables with sums, one for the listed brands, one for the non listed brands:

sumOst

```
function(){
var prods = {{productList}};  
var i;
var sum = 0;   
if (!prods) { return; }
for (i = 0; i < prods.length; i++) { if (!(prods[i].id in ["BRANDC" || "BRANDD"])) {
sum +=(prods[i].price)
} } 
return sum; 
}
```

and sumTop

```
function(){
var prods = {{productList}};  
var i;
var sum = 0;   
if (!prods) { return; }
for (i = 0; i < prods.length; i++) { if (prods[i].id in ["BRANDC" || "BRANDD"]) {
sum +=(prods[i].price)
} } 
return sum; 
}
```

The result is written all the same for both cases: 103.3199.0030.00
I quess there some problem with the condition if?

Then I created two variables priceNettoTop and priceNettoOst

```
function() {
return({{sumTop}} * 0.104);
}
```

and

```
function() {
return({{sumOst}} * 0.052);
}
```

It did gave result, but from the bad input 103.3199.0030.00

And then I created variable price, which is the sum I need

```
function() {
return({{priceNettoOst}} + {{priceNettoTop}});
}
```

And this gives me no result.
I would appreciate every hint, what to look for. Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "prods[i].brand in ["BRANDC" || "BRANDD"]" (instead of prods[i].id, which will never be in your specified array) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has no relation to GTM. It's JS. You forget to parseInt your string price value.
Here, a test for you:

```js
var prods = {"products":[{"name":"Product1","id":"xyz","price":"103.31","quantity":1,"brand":"BRANDA"},{"name":"Product2","id":"xzy","price":"99.00","quantity":1,"brand":"BRANDB"},{"name":"Product3","id":"zyx","price":"30.00","quantity":1,"brand":"BRANDC"}]};//hardcoding this for a test.

var sum = 0

prods.products.forEach(function(product){
    sum += parseFloat(product.price);
})

console.log(sum);
```

Switched to parseFloat as per Eike's suggestion.

Also try to use array functions like .filter() or .forEach(). Makes your code a lot prettier. And functional.

Comment: Given that the prices have numbers behind the decimal point, parseFloat might be more appropriate.